# How to use :last-child + :after together?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why this isn't working. I'm trying to change the `:after` rule for the `:last-child` element, but it's ignoring `:last-child:after`.

HTML:

```
<section id="timeline">
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#timeline article:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background: #222;
    z-index:1;
}

#timeline article:last-child:after {background:none!important}
```

**Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cd8g2hs0/4/**

I've found other questions about this issue, and it seems like I'm doing it correctly. But obviously I'm not!

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351623/combining-css-pseudo-elements-after-the-last-child

Comment: I had already looked at that question, but it suggests what I'm already doing. Am I missing something?

Comment: It _is_ working – you’re just not seeing any effect, because _all_ your :after pseudo elements are as high as the whole .timeline element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351623/combining-css-pseudo-elements-after-the-last-child as well

Comment: Check this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351623/combining-css-pseudo-elements-after-the-last-child

Comment: You'll also want to close your image tags />, and possibly using :: for modern browsers as well as single : colons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your code is working - it's just not producing the result you expect.

Try changing the first line of your CSS in the fiddle to the following:

```
#timeline article {padding:0;position:relative}
```

Does this get your desired result?

Comment: D'oh! I can't believe I forgot the "position:relative" -- that was it. Once I added that, it worked just fine. Thanks. I'll mark correct once I can.