# I use the li:after to add content after the li, but not work., I tried to solve the problem by nav ol li ::after ,nav ol li *::after but Not work

Tags: html, css

I used `li:after` to add content after the `li` element, but it didn't work. 
I tried to solve the problem with `nav ol li::after`, `nav ol li*::after`, but it didn't work.

[Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEwPZ.png)

Here's the code I used:

```
nav ol li::after {
  content: "|";
}

nav ol li:last-child {
  content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides having extra spaces. You also need to [combine the css pseudo-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351623/combining-css-pseudo-elements-after-the-last-child). It should be `li:last-child::after` and `li::after`.

[Check the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndeprsv6/15/)